# TableSorter + AJAX to get data from MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter

I have managed to integrate tablesorter into a Joomla template, so as to display the content of K2 Extra Fields from K2 Categories into a table.

Layout and functionality is 100% as I want it, perfect!! It even uses Joomla ACL to limit row data too!

However, with just a sample of 1800 K2 Items, the pages takes a long time to load and the quantity will only get bigger.

I have looked at AJAX for server side loading, but for the life of me, I just do not understand the documentation to be able to get AJAX to function.

At present I am using the bootstrap table sorter as seen here: http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-bootstrap-theme.html

Any suggestions to load data quicker?

Any help for a non coder would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share some code.

Answer (score 0):

You must create you own navigation paging and load data page by page from the database, control using SQL query LIMIT and OFFSET and load on request using AJAX.

```
//This is PHP code:

$totalRecord = ??? //get this using SELECT COUNT
$totalRecordPerPage = 50; //this is up to you!!!

//get total pages
$totalPage = floor($totalRecord / $totalRecordPerPage); //floor;
$modResult = $totalRecord % $totalRecordPerPage; 
if ($modResult <> 0)
    $totalPage++;

$pageNo =  $_GET["pageno"]; //FROM AJAX GET

//set the SQL limit and offset
$limit = $totalRecordPerPage;
$offset = (($pageNo - 1) * $totalRecordPerPage);

$sql = "SELECT bla bla bla
        FROM bla1, bla2
        WHERE bla bla bla
        ORDER BY bla blabla ASC  
        limit $limit
        offset $offset";   

$sqlResult = mysql_query($sql, $con); //this is only an example, use PDO for security
//create JSON from result 
//use that JSON to update tablesorter

//JAVASCRIPT AJAX
//tblHTML is a tr and td that contain JSON data from the AJAX result 
$("#tblbody").html(tblHTML);
$(".tablesorter").trigger("update");
```

NEVER load all the data at once

[image]